# Cannot use local 'i' as parameter to non-global template

Tags: d, d-templates

```d
template IsSame(T){
  template As(alias t){
    enum As = is(T : typeof(t));
  }
}
void main()
{
  int i;
  enum b = IsSame!int.As!(i);
}
```

Err:

> Error: template instance As!(i) cannot use local 'i' as parameter to
>   non-global template As(alias t) dmd failed with exit code 1

I don't understand the error message.

I also tried

```d
template IsSame(T){
  enum As(alias t) = is(T : typeof(t));
}
```

Which results in

> Error: template app.IsSame!int.As cannot deduce function from argument
>   types !()(int), candidates are: source/app.d(50,8):
>   app.IsSame!int.As(alias t)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you use `enum` for `b` instead of `bool`?

Comment: I need it at compile time, not sure if bool would suffice for this.

Answer (score 1):

In dmd 2.069.0 and dmd 2.065, it works fine when `i` is global:

```d
import std.stdio;

template IsSame(T){
  template As(alias t){
    enum As = is(T : typeof(t));
  }
}

int i;

void main()
{
  bool b = IsSame!int.As!(i);
  writeln(b); // true
}
```

The [documentation for template alias parameters](http://dlang.org/template.html#aliasparameters) claims these allow the template to be parameterized with local names, too, but fails to provide an example on how to do that:

> Alias parameters enable templates to be parameterized with any type of D symbol, including global names, **local names**, module names, template names, and template instance names. Literals can also be used as arguments to alias parameters.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: It works if I mark the template as static like `staitc template IsSame(T){`

Comment: For completeness, you might want to post the working code as an answer of your own.